# Visualize org.joda.time.DateTime as String in Postman

Tags: json, datetime, jodatime

I parse a String to org.joda.time.DateTime, via the following code:

```
DateTime submitDateTime = DateTime.parse("2019-10-14T09:08:40.000+0000");
```

I assign this date time then to a field in an object (dateSent)

```
public class SmsEntry {
    private String smsId;
    private String status;
    private String text;
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String type;
    private DateTime dateSent;
    private DateTime dateReceived;

}
```

After that an array of such objects is the result of calling a GET method to a endpoint.
There this date is represented as json node:

```
            "dateSent": {
                "year": 2019,
                "dayOfMonth": 14,
                "dayOfWeek": 1,
                "dayOfYear": 287,
                "era": 1,
                "hourOfDay": 9,
                "minuteOfHour": 8,
                "secondOfMinute": 40,
                "millisOfSecond": 0,
                "centuryOfEra": 20,
                "yearOfEra": 2019,
                "yearOfCentury": 19,
                "weekyear": 2019,
                "monthOfYear": 10,
                "weekOfWeekyear": 42,
                "millisOfDay": 32920000,
                "secondOfDay": 32920,
                "minuteOfDay": 548,
                "zone": {
                    "fixed": true,
                    "id": "UTC"
                },
                "millis": 1571044120000,
                "chronology": {
                    "zone": {
                        "fixed": true,
                        "id": "UTC"
                    }
                },
                "afterNow": false,
                "beforeNow": true,
                "equalNow": false
            }
```

Meanwhile if I have just this code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(dateToParse);
        System.out.println(dt.toString());
    }
```

The result is this string:

```
2019-10-14T09:08:40.000Z
```

What do I have to do in order to have such string visualized instead of JSON node, when calling the endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using Java. If you are using Jackson to serialize your objects into JSON, add the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And register [`JodaModule`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-joda/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/JodaModule.html) in your [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda) for details.